# What should I pass to duplex WCF client instance context

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex-channel

Here is a generated proxy for my duplex WCF service:

```
 public partial class MyWcfServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase<Ifa.WcfClients.ServiceReference1.IMyWcfService>, Ifa.WcfClients.ServiceReference1.IMyWcfService {

    public MyWcfServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance) : 
            base(callbackInstance) {
    }            
      .
      .
      .
}
```

I want to inherit from this class and build a new class like this:

```
public class WcfClientBase : MyWcfServiceClient
{
    public WcfClientBase() : base(???)
    {
    }

    somemethod1(){....}
    somemethod2(){....}    
}
```

My problem is that the base class needs an argument of `InstanceContext`. What should I pass as this argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a duplex setup right? Meaning the server communicates results back via callbacks.

So the client needs to specify the class which has these callback methods - which will get invoked on replies from server.

You need to write a class implementing the callback interface (it'll be part of your service contract) and then pass an object of this class to the InstanceContext.

Comment: yes it is. so if server calls client methods, does my methods declared in WcfClientBase are called? or the methods declared in callback class?

Comment: They will be the methods in the object you passed to InstanceContext, which would be the callback class.

Comment: accodring to this, i can not create a subclass form duplex wcf client